# Как сделать анимированный задний фон? React/CSS

Tags: reactjs, scss

Всем доброго вечера! Помогите пожалуйста, создаю сайт и хочу на задний фон поставить анимацию-гифку. Есть видео из 10 сек, где на фоне всплывают пузырьки.
Как мне это сделать? Приложение пишу на React и SCSS.

```
class Contacts extends Component {
  render() {
    return(<div className={styles.container}>
      <video className={styles.bubbles} loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted">
        <source src={bubbles} type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E030, mp4a.40.2"' />
        {/* <source src="video/bubbles.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
        <source src="video/bubbles.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' /> */}
      </video>
      <div className={styles.contactsInfo}>
        <div>
          <p className={styles.come}>&#8212;</p>
          <p className={styles.come}>Приходите</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className={styles.adress}>ул. Рубинштейна 48, Санкт-Петербург, 191002, Россия</p>
          <p className={styles.adress}>info@secretofkoko.ru \ +7-931-456-54-46</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className={styles.workTime}>ЧАСЫ РАБОТЫ</p>
          <p className={styles.workTime}>ПН-ПТ: 9:00-22:00 \ СБ: 10:00-21:00 \ ВС: 10:00-20:00</p>
        </div>
        <form>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Имя*' className={styles.info}/>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Email*' className={styles.info}/>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Телефон' className={styles.info}/>
          <input type='text' placeholder='Сообщение' className={styles.message}/>
          {/* <textarea placeholder='Введите текст'></textarea> */}
          <button>Отправить</button>
        </form>
        <p>Посмотреть на карте></p>
      </div>
    </div>)
  }
}

export default Contacts;
```

Comment: Добавь лучше видео, чем gif. Качество будет лучше)

Comment: Хорошо, у меня есть 14-сек видео, как мне его сделать задним фоном?

Comment: Добавьте тег video и сделайте его позиционирование fixed, а поверх весь контент. Тегу видео можно добавить атрибуты `autoplay preload loop muted`

Comment: а атрибуты какому свойству приписываются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте внутри тега `<body>` файла `index.html` примерно следующее:

```
<body>
      <video class="bubbles" width="640" height="360" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted">
              <source src="video/bubbles.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E030, mp4a.40.2"'>
              <source src="video/bubbles.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
              <source src="video/bubbles.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
      </video>
</body>
```

Соответственно в папке `video` должны быть 3 видеофайла `bubles` в соответствующих форматах.
Также надо добавить стили для этого элемента:

```
.clouds
{
    display: block;
    top: -20%;
    left: -20%;
    width: 140%;
    height: 140%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    -o-object-fit: contain;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: А можно еще вопрос. У меня приложение написано на реакте, я включил все это в одной из компонент, но проблема в том,  что при свойстве fixed у меня это видео на заднем фоне плавает зафиксировано по всему экрану, а мне нужно, чтобы у меня было закреплено лишь в 1 компоненте, а не по всей странице сайта. Что мне нужно сделать для этого?

Comment: надо смотреть код

Comment: Хорошо, тогда другой вопрос. Как сделать чтобы это был именно задний фон? А то у меня видео ведет себя как главный компонент и вытесняет мою основную компоненту вбок.

Comment: Код, пожалуйста, в студию :)

Comment: добавил код в вопрос) css полностью ваш, единственное я изменил position на absolute и убрал top & left - так он встал на задний фон в одной компоненте по центру. А так же width - 100% & height - 107%. Но он не на всю компоненту, а на только на большую его часть, мне нужно как-то закрыть им всю компоненту.

Comment: Все я решил проблему. Нужно именно в js code указать свойство width-100% и поставить position: absolute.